# ESLint not detecting imported React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atom-editor, eslint, linter

I am having an issue with ESLint not detecting imported React components with a 'no-unused-vars' rule. My components are imported:

```
import MediaQuery from 'react-responsive';
```

and the component is used further down in the file:

```
render() {
  return (
    <MediaQuery maxDeviceWidth={750}>
      <div style={styles.iconMobileContainerRight} >
        <i className="fa fa-chevron-right" style={styles.checkboxMobile} aria-hidden="true" ></i>
      </div>
    </MediaQuery>
  );
}
```

My .eslintrc.js file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
};
```

I am using the atom text editor with the linter and linter-eslint packages installed (both up to date with the latest releases). What am I missing to make the linter detect the use of the imported component?

Comment: @MayankShukla The errors is 'no-unused-vars'. You can read more about it at the eslint docs: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

Comment: No, it appears to have to do with my React configuration, but I'm not sure what. I'm not super familiar with ESLint and how it needs to be configured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ESLint by default does not detect variables used in JSX. To mark them as used, you should use the [jsx-uses-vars](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-vars.md) rule of the [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) plugin.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Comment: It took me a while to get this setting enabled - the naming is not very intuitive. It needs `"rules": { "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error" }`